# How to save images using filename of data from CSV file in R?

Tags: r, filenames

I have a CSV file called `data` which contains latitude and longitude coordinates. A sample:

```
Lat    Lon
13.3   100.3
23.2   90.3
```

Using an API key, I can retrieve Google Street View images using these coordinates which are saved on my computer with the `googleway` package. They are saved as .jpeg files.

The code below loops through the coordinates in `data`, gets the associated image and saves them as e.g. `image_00001.jpeg`, `image_00002.jpeg`, etc.

```
jpeg('image_%05d.jpeg')
purrr::map2(data$Lat, data$Lon, function)
dev.off()
```

However, instead of saving these files as e.g. `image_00001.jpeg`, I want the filename to be the coordinates that correspond to the image. So for instance, if the image is from the `13.3, 100.3` coordinate pair/row from `data`, I want to save the file as `13.3-100.3.jpeg`.

Does anybody know how to do this?

Comment: In your `function` you just need to save the file as `paste0(Lat, "-", Lon, ".jpeg")` or something similar

Comment: I’m not sure you needed to make 3 different posts for what is essentially the same question.

Comment: @AndrewGustar please could you give an example by amending the original code? As I'm not sure where to put this in the function

Answer (score 0):

As Andrew Gustar stated in his comment. You can use `paste` in your loop to generate rowwise filenames of your data.

```
data <- data.frame(Lat = c(13.3, 23.2),
                   Lon = c(100.3, 90.3))
data
   Lat   Lon
1 13.3 100.3
2 23.2  90.3
 
sapply(1:nrow(data), function(x) return(paste0(paste(data[x,], collapse = "-"), ".jpeg")))
[1] "13.3-100.3.jpeg" "23.2-90.3.jpeg"
```

Comment: Thanks! I ended up using the solution posited by Andrew Gustar, but perhaps you can help with something. I amended the last 3 lines of my code to `jpeg(paste0(data$Lat, "-", data$Lon, ".jpeg"))
purrr::map2(data$Lat, data$Lon, MyFunction)
dev.off()`, but it only saves the last image to my hard drive and not all of them. Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: `jpeg()` is not vectorized, so you have to loop over each string in you vector.

Comment: Would you be able to provide an example, please? For instance, if I used `jpeg('image%05d.jpeg')` instead of `jpeg(paste0(data$Lat, "-", data$Lon, ".jpeg"))`, then it does save each image (but it doesn't save them with the filename I want).